# How to add data in localStorage from server

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have some problem. How can I save data in localStorage that had been responsed from server? Maybe I should use localStorage.setItem? But how to put an array here? Or I made a mistake?

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
export class Contact {
  constructor(
    public name:string,
    public username:string,
    public email:string,
    public phone:string,
    public website:string
  ) {}
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact-list',
  templateUrl: './contact-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact-list.component.css']
})
export class ContactListComponent implements OnInit {
  
  contacts: Contact[] = [];

  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.contacts = [];
    this.getContacts();
  }
  getContacts() {
    this.httpClient.get<any>('some url').subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.contacts = response;  
      }
    );
  }


}
```

Comment: Why you are not storing in an object? Because If the data is too much then it will going to impact on your application performance or if there is some sensitive data into it, its then its not recommended to store on the client side. I would prefer you should store the data an object in the form of ```keyValue``` pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local Storage stores pairs of key/value, which are strings. So you have to serialize it when you save, and deserialize when you try to retrieve this data.

```
const data = ['value 1', 'value 2' ... ];
localStorage.setItem('somekey', JSON.stringify(data));

const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('somekey'));
```